# Number of unique items queried in DynamoDB for given time period

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I want to know the number of unique items being queried from (Get/BatchGet) DynamoDB for given time period (say per day), is there a way to figure it out?

For example: 500 unique documents were queried in last 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can log all data plane activities to CloudTrail and query the logs:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/now-you-can-use-aws-cloudtrail-to-log-data-plane-api-activity-in-your-amazon-dynamodb-tables/